# Reload a single DIV on a page using onClick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my page there are several DIVs, which are supposed to show different news items depending on the user selection and a press of a submit button.

Am I able to refresh only a single DIV when the relevant submit button is clicked?

I tried `<input type ="button">` instead of `<input type="submit">` but that didn't work as expected. My code is below:

```
<div class="dloader"></div>
<div class="search">
    <form action="" method="post">
        Furniture: 
        <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1" value="<?=$_POST['val1']?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</div>

<?php
    if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
        $postItemHeader = htmlentities($_POST['val1']); 
}?>

<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(".dloader").fadeOut("slow");
    })
</script>
```

Comment: To refresh only a specific `div` on form submission you need to use AJAX

Comment: especially if you're submitting data, AJAX is necessary, unless it was content that's not going server side

Comment: What made you think `<input type ="button">` would do the job?

Comment: you can use jquery load() function aslo... but u need to place that new code of that div in a new file and need to call that on load function

Comment: @user0000000 `load()` is indeed AJAX, however it does not submit posted form values.

Comment: Which div are you trying to refresh? If it is `.dloader` why are you fading it out?

Answer (score 1):

**Take One Button For Post Event**

```
<input type="submit" id="add" name="add" />
```

**If You want to pass the Text Data, so a text value from the Text to fetch the particular data**

```
<div id="result">Result should appear here</div>
```

**Use Javascript To POst The Text Data To Back End**

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#add').val,
            success: function(data, status) {
                $("#result").html(data)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You should probably show how to use this within the context of the OP's code rather than posting a generic example. In addition, please explain what you have done so that future visitors to SO will understand the implementation.

Comment: Your edits still do not place this within the context of the OP's markup. You're also using ID's and the OP has many of these divs that he would like to reload.

Comment: It is my logic I am not here to change their code. If you think it is not efficient then please help OP with your code.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). (read the documentation). A simple example is here.

The HTML

```
<div id="target_div"></div> <!-- Here is where you gonna place your new content -->

<input type='button' id='trigger' onClick="get_new_data()" value="Get new Content"> <!-- When this button is pressed get new content -->
```

The Javascript

```
function get_new_data()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: POST,
        url: "you-url-here.php",
        dataType:"HTML", // May be HTML or JSON as your wish
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('div#target_div').html(data) // The server's response is now placed inside your target div
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("Failed to get data.");
        }
    }); // Ajax close
    return false; // So the button click does not refresh the page
} // Function end
```